# Is there a library that emulates facebook's "Link Detect"?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, facebook

I'm looking to write a library that "parses" information like facebook does when you post a link. However as I don't want to reinvent the wheel does anyone know of a library or and effort to write an Library that does this already?

I have included an example so that you can get a grasp of what I mean if you don't use face book. http://lh4.ggpht.com/_zbED-KN_ZAI/Sx6LuDmZkVI/AAAAAAAADLs/mN7eFnzL1gE/s144/example.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't seen any library for that, but looks a pretty simple thing. I've jot down a quick function which can help you out. I have kept it simple, you might want to use cURL to fetch the content, put some error handling, etc.

Anyway, here is my two cents:

```
<?php

function getLinkInfo($url)
{
    // Get target link html
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    // Prepare the DOM document
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

    // Get page title
    $titles = $dom->getElementsByTagname('title');
    foreach ($titles as $title) {
        $linkTitle = $title->nodeValue;
    }

    // Get META tags
    $metas = $dom->getElementsByTagname('meta'); 

    // We only need description
    foreach ($metas as $meta) {
        if ($meta->getAttribute("name") == "description") {
            $linkDesc = $meta->getAttribute("content");
        }
    }

    // Get all images
    $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagname('img'); 

    // Again, we need the first one only
    foreach ($imgs as $img) {
        $firstImage = $img->getAttribute("src");

        if (strpos("http://", $firstImage) === false) {
            $firstImage = $url . $firstImage; 
        }

        break;
    }

    $output = <<<HTML

    <div class="info">

        <div class="image"><img src="{$firstImage}" alt="{$linkTitle}" /></div>
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="title">{$linkTitle}</div>
            <div class="subtitle">{$url}</div>
            <div class="summary">{$linkDesc}</div>
        </div>

    </div>

HTML;

    return $output;
}

echo getLinkInfo("http://www.phpfour.com/");
```

Comment: Thanks, now to figure out how to code it in ASP

Answer (score 1):

John Gruber has [a regex pattern](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) that might help:

> A common programming problem:
>   identify the URLs in an arbitrary
>   string of text, where by “arbitrary”
>   let’s agree we mean something
>   unstructured such as an email message
>   or a tweet.