# Textbox link preview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox, migration

I have to create an application for link and video sharing, similar to facebook. I tried to search any tutorial/demo/code snippet for the same. There are tons for tutorial in php to do that

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646147/is-there-open-source-code-for-making-link-preview-text-and-icons-like-in-face)
- [Link 2](http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/)
- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868544/is-there-a-library-that-emulates-facebooks-link-detect)
- [Link 4](http://lab.leocardz.com/facebook-link-preview-php--jquery/)

Unfortunately, I didn't find any tutorial on ASP.NET. I also tried to convert the php code to asp.net but due my *zero* level knowledge in PHP I am not able to convert it completely. I did install [PHP to ASP.NET 1.x migration](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet) but as per tutorial it is not reflecting on VS2005, VS2008 & VS2010.

Can anyone guide me how I can implement the same with asp.net? Or how I can convert the existing code from php to asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a pretty simple language to pick up and certainly isn't something that would convert to asp.net without a LOT of rework as the conceptual model is just totally different.

I'd suggest you take a look at the [php.net](http://php.net/) site, specifically the [language reference area](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php).  That site is the go to place for understanding php.  You may also want to start with a [simple example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php) and work up from there.  That way you can start reading your existing code to figure out what each function call means.

The good news is that php and c# share the same root language so things like `foreach` work pretty much identically between the two.

After you've gone through a bit of that, come back and post a question about a specific problem you are having or a specific area of the php code you don't understand.

Finally, if your willing to look a project that does this whose only requirement is the usage of json, then check out http://embed.ly